# How dynamic pass gql schema's for refetch?

Tags: reactjs, apollo

Can I pass gql`query for refetch.
In some vars I need refetch with different scheamas

```
 gql`query
  Products (
    $afterCursor: String,
    $first: Int!,
  ){
    products (
      afterCursor: $afterCursor,
      first: $first,
    ) {
      items {
        email
        
  }
`;
```

or

```
 gql`query
  Products (
    $afterCursor: String,
     $search: String
    $first: Int!,
  ){
    products (
      afterCursor: $afterCursor,
      first: $first,
      search: $search
    ) {
      items {
        email
        
  }
`;

 const refetchRequest = (rest) => refetch({
    ...rest,
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

In a refetch the query and the list of variables are fixed but the *values* of the variables and `fetchPolicy` can be different. I suggest you use:

```js
gql`query
  Products (
    $afterCursor: String,
     $search: String
    $first: Int!,
  ){
    products (
      afterCursor: $afterCursor,
      first: $first,
      search: $search
    ) {
      items {
        email
        
  }
`;
```

for both the initial query and refetch but use a value of `null` or `undefined` for `$search` for the initial query. Of course your resolver would need to expect that.